# Как с помощью серлета ответить ajax запросу и перенаправить на html страницу?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

Как с помощью сервлета ответить данному `ajax` запросу и перенаправить пользователя на другую `html` страницу.

На странице `login.html` есть такой `jquery` скрипт

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#login-button").click(function () {
            var userPassword = $("input#userPassword").val();
            var userLogin = $("input#userLogin").val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "login",
                data: {login: userLogin, password: userPassword},
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Successful request! Data is " + data.toString());

                    }
                },
                dataType: "text",
                error: function (jqXHR) {
                    console.log(jqXHR);
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

Мне нужно, чтобы сервлет ответил на запрос и сам же(сервлет) перенаправил на другую `html` страницу. Как это должно выглядеть?

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/plain");
        response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        response.getWriter().print("message");
        response.getWriter().close();
        // Так он передает управление обратно скрипту и не перенаправляет на welcome.html
        response.sendRedirect("welcome.html");

}
```

Comment: Передавайте на клиента url и там присваивайте document.location.href = url.

Comment: Вот мне как раз это не нужно, поскольку тогда потеряются данные из HttpSession  и response(я для простоты примера убрал код, к делу не относяшийся)

Comment: AJAX /  XMLHttpRequest не редиректится. Хотя спецификация говорит, что должен, до сих пор такой поддержки в браузерах не было. Поэтому все давно шлют URL клиенту и редиректят с него - как вам и было сказано выше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Видится непонимание как работают сервлеты.
Весь сеанс связи клиента с сервером это запрос-ответ, запрос-ответ...
Для обработки запроса создаётся свой экземпляр сервлета. Этот экземпляр должен выдать ответ и только один ответ. Перенаправление - это тоже ответ. После ответа экземпляр стразу уничтожается.

Сервлеты - это не те программы, которые все привыкли писать, когда сами контролируете когда запускается, в какой момент что-то делает, когда завершает работу.
Это обработчики событий со строгим регламентом. Вызываются сервером, когда он считает нужным, и ожидает от них определённого поведения.

```
        response.getWriter().close();
        // Так он передает управление обратно скрипту и не перенаправляет на welcome.html
        response.sendRedirect("welcome.html");
```

Так `sendRedirect` в принципе работать не может. В предыдущей строке (не комментарии) Вы уже закрыли ответ. Либо сразу ридерект, либо никогда.

Для поддержания сессии, как верно отмечено используется `HttpSession`. При обработке каждого запроса можно создать сессию. Последующие запросы того же клиента будут автоматически привязаны к этой сессии и будут иметь доступ к общей памяти. Всё данные, необходимые для поддержки сессии складываются и извлекаются из `HttpSession`.

Как работает ajax с редиректами сам не проверял, но люди говорят примерно так.
Если в ответ на ajax идёт redirect, то браузер его перехватывает, сам выполняет этот redirect и в результате ajax-у отдаёт полностью страницу, куда было перенаправление.
Наверное это не лучший вариант для ajax, поэтому поступают как пишет Владимир в комментарии:

> Передавайте на клиента url и там присваивайте document.location.href =
>   url

В сервлете login Вам необходимо создать сессию, заполнить её нужными данными, выполнить ajax-редирект

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
    session.setAttribute("user", user);
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().print("welcome.html");
}
```

Как в ajax обработать welcome.html не скажу. Сами придумайте. javascript явно не мой конёк.

Сервлет welcome продолжает работать с httpsession

```
protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(flase); // false не создавать сессию, использовать которая уже открыта или null когда сессии нет
    if (session == null) {
        // здесь тем или иным образом перенаправить на login
        return;
    }
    String user = (String)session.getAttribute("user", user);
    session.setAttribute("Для кучи", new Object());
    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
    response.getWriter().print("welcome " + user);
}
```

Таким образом ничего не должно пропадать. Только куки не забудьте разрешить в браузере.

Для сервлетов придумали кучу всяких полезных штук, что прямое общение с HttpSession сводится к минимуму. Например CDI внедряет в сервлеты уже готовые объекты, которые могут иметь разную область видимости. Один живут на протяжении всей сессии, другие создаются только на время обработки текущего запроса. Так же подключаются базы данных. Только повозится в конфигурации придётся.